# Logging SKLearn Models in the same folder while running multiple models in Pandas UDF

Tags: pandas, pyspark, azure-databricks, sklearn-pandas, mlflow

I am trying to run multiple XGBoost models and save the resulting models in the form of experiments. However, when I call the UDF function on my pyspark dataframe the models are being saved in a multiple folders.

It appears that they are being randomly split in smaller batches and stored. Is there a way to ensure that all models are saved in the same run/ folder such that I can easily load them back later.

```
def classification_xgb(df):
  #modeling code
  mlflow.sklearn.log_model(xgb, model_name)


dat_m.groupBy("Product").applyInPandas(classification_xgb, schema).show(10000,False)
```

I have over 100 products for which I need to create models and save in the same run instance.